# Accessing Ledger on a Multi-channel multi-chaincode and multi-ledger Fabric network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I want to build a HyperLedger Fabric network where I have a 2 orgs. Org1 has a Ledger(CounchDB) L1 which contains user data. Org2 has Ledger(CounchDB) L2 which has some data of its own.

Now Org2 wants to access some predefined data-points form Org1's L1.

What should be my system architecture to make sure that Org2 accesses only the predefined data-points and the whole of L1 remains completely invisible.

Both, Org1 and Org2 have their separate sets of operations which should be invisible to another organization.

My initial line of thought was to make 3 channels. 2 for individual orgs and 1 for cross org communication. What I don't know is how to access ledger of another channel from a channel.

Comment: Well, I would use private collection feature to let organizations store their sensitive data. And keep only those data in the ledger which would be relevant to complete transactions or can be shared among organization. Private collections would help, and reduce the number of channels you might require.

Comment: Thanks Niraj. I'll try this solution

Comment: @Niraj Kumar. Your solution will help me in privatising the database. But how do I privatise the chaincode logic? Won't 1 channel need the same chaincode

Comment: You should not worry about that. That's why we have private collection and private collection configuration where you mention the organizations who should have access to private collections. For every set of organizations you would be creating that many set of private collections and configurations.
I would highly recommend that you go through the documentation for more clarity and better understanding.
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/private_data_tutorial.html